# get number of rows with pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo, rows

I have a simple pdo prepared query:

```
$result = $db->prepare("select id, course from coursescompleted where person=:p"); 
$result ->bindParam(':p', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $rows[0];
```

the echo seems to be returning the ID value of the record, not the number of records returned by the query?

any idea or explanation for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**PDO::FETCH_NUM:**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0

You aren't fetching the row-count at all.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coursescompleted where person=:p
```

This query would return total rows in `$rows[0];`

**EDIT:**
Please see @ray's answer. using `count(id)` is better than `count(*)` for InnoDB.

---

You could get row-count in the following manner, from your earlier query.

```
$row_count = $result->rowCount();
```

**But be warned:**

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

[**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. my problem is in my body I fetch the returmed results using `while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` how could I accomplich both with a single mysql query or do I need two for each function? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you try `$row_count = $result->rowCount();` with your old query? Some report that PDO_MySQL driver allows that to work, despite the documentation saying otherwise.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I think you could still count the rows in PHP as you iterate through the rows, in `fetch`. Not sure how bad that is though.

Comment: You said you were using the contents of the query also, does that mean you now run 2 queries, one for row count and one for the actual data?

Answer (score 18):

You've executed a query that returns rows from the database, fetched the first row from the result into a variable and then echo'd the first column of that row.

If you want to count, do an SQL count()

```
$result = $db->prepare("select count(*) from coursescompleted where person=:p"); 
$result->bindParam(':p', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
$rowCount = $result->fetchColumn(0);
echo $rowCount;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `id` is the primary key use:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coursescompleted WHERE person=:p;
```

Avoid a count(*). If your storage engine is InnoDB (possibly others except MyIsam) you'll take a performance hit.

Comment: Are you certain there is a performance hit? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1697144/759019) says otherwise, for mysql.

Comment: @Cthulhu I'm certain.  MyISAM can do count(*) and count(id) if id is a PK in the same amount of time (memory tables too are good with count(*)'s), but if your table is Innodb storage engine you're going to shoot your foot: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo count($rows);` as `$rows` is an array.

Edit:

To use the results

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(/* nothing here */);
if(count($rows) > 0) {
  // Show results, perhaps using a foreach($rows as $row)
} else {
 echo "Sorry, no results found";
}
```

Comment: This would give him the number of columns fetched, i.e. 2, every time.

PDOStatement::fetch() returns a single row. PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns the entire result set as an array

Comment: That's what the question is asking "the echo seems to be returning the ID value of the record, `not the number of records returned` by the query?"

Comment: Though I suppose it doesn't look like he actually needs the query contents, so an SQL `count()` is preferable.

Comment: the number of records returned !== the number of columns in each record.

Comment: Thanks, I need the query content and the number of rows. so if there is content, display it or if no content show user message the there is no content... if that makes sense. thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger: Sounds like you could just execute the query normally then use the `count($rows)` to see if it found anything, I'll expand answer a little.

Comment: Using PHP 7.1 and the PDO library this is the *only* thing that works that is not intrusive to the code.  Porting from PHP 5.6 and there is no easy way to get numRows.   rowCount() returns -1, so that's no good.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
<?php
$result = $db->prepare("select id, course from coursescompleted where person=:p"); 
$result ->bindParam(':p', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->rowCount();
echo $rows;
?>
```

This sometimes does not work on `SELECT` queries. But based on personal experience, and since you didn't mention porting it to other database systems, it should work on MySQL.

More info is in PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)